# Performing a multivariate dynlm on xts object

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I am trying to perform this operation within an xts object, but I am obtaining an error. The libraries and data used are:

```
#Libraries
library(xts)
library(dynlm)

#Data
index <- seq.Date(from = Sys.Date() - 999, to = Sys.Date(), by = "days")
x <- xts(1:1000, order.by = index)
y <- xts(2001:3000, order.by = index)
z <- xts(3001:4000, order.by = index)
data <- merge(x,y,z)
```

And I am trying to perform this dynamic regression

```
dynlm(x ~ L(y) + L(z,4), data = data)
```

Any thoughts? Or should I just convert the information as a dataframe and work from there.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed is to use the dyn package.  (Be sure that dplyr is NOT loaded since dplyr overwrites `lag` with its own version that is incompatible with the rest of R.)

```
library(dyn)
dyn$lm(x ~ lag(y) + lag(z, 4), data = data)
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dyn(x ~ lag(y) + lag(z, 4)), data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       lag(y)    lag(z, 4)  
      -1999            1           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that dynlm does not work well with 'xts' objects.

One solution given by Grothendieck suggests using a different package (which works).

Another solution is to change the object to zoo.

Nevertheless, this was confusing as the object I was working initially was class: "xts" "zoo"; and dynlm was not recognizing the 'zoo' part.

After changing it to 'zoo' everything works if somebody wants to stay with this package.

```
#Libraries
library(xts)
library(dynlm)

#Data
index <- seq.Date(from = Sys.Date() - 999, to = Sys.Date(), by = "days")
x <- xts(1:1000, order.by = index)
y <- xts(2001:3000, order.by = index)
z <- xts(3001:4000, order.by = index)
data <- merge(x,y,z)

data.zoo <- zoo(data, order.by = index(data))

dynlm(x ~ L(y) + L(z,4), data = data.zoo)
```

Giving

```
Time series regression with "zoo" data:
Start = 2017-05-23, End = 2020-02-12

Call:
dynlm(formula = x ~ L(y) + L(z, 4), data = data.zoo)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         L(y)      L(z, 4)  
      -1999            1           NA
```

Curiosly, the intercept obtained is different.

Comment: The reason they were different was that I forgot that lag.xts works in the opposite direction to lag in the base of R so lagging by one using lag.xts is lag(y, 1) whereas in base R it is lag(y, -1).  I regard this as a design error in xts. They really should have used a different name, not lag, if they wanted to use a different convention. Anyways, I have fixed my answer.  Note that if you want to convert data to zoo you can just use as.zoo(data).